# App force closes on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, forceclose

I have an `Activity` with a `Button` which `Intent` is relative to how the `Activity` was launched. The previous `Activity` is a `ListView` that passes extra to this `Activity` to define different values for the `Button` click `Intents`. Please take a look at my code below;

```
public class ContentViewer extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int chooser = bundle.getInt("Layout");

    switch(chooser) {
    case 0:
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        break;

    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.contentviewer);
        break;

    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 5:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 6:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 7:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 8:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 9:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;
    }

    final int linker = bundle.getInt("Layout");
    Button vlink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videolink);
    vlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               switch(linker) {  
            case 0:
                Intent v0 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + "0lh_UWF9ZP4"));
                        startActivity(v0); 
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent v1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + "0lh_UWF9ZP4"));
                        startActivity(v1); 
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent v2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + "0lh_UWF9ZP4"));
                        startActivity(v2); 
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Whenever I click the button, the app force closes. I dont have any idea where my errors might be. Heres the error log;

```
01-10 00:03:40.895: W/dalvikvm(5759): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c271f8)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.borislemke.cookingwithdog/com.borislemke.cookingwithdog.ContentViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at com.borislemke.cookingwithdog.ContentViewer.onCreate(ContentViewer.java:61)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
01-10 00:03:40.900: E/AndroidRuntime(5759):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: would be nice if someone could explain the situation! :)

Comment: Something in line 61 is `null` and should not be. Which one is line 61?

Comment: What's on line 61 of `ContentViewer.java`?

Comment: @alextsc vlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a button in your XML layout that has the id "videolink"? Your vLink button is null because it can't find the UI element to map to. Can you paste the layout xml?

I'm not familiar with what you're doing with the chooser -- is there not a layout you'd like to load from the beginning that contains the button?

Comment: Seems to be a typo here! Duhh, how embarassing.. Okay, found the problem. It works on item 2 and 3, but in the layout which is inflated in case 1, the buttons id was mistyped

Comment: And thanks for the answer! I will work more carefully from now on.. Im really sorry to all!

Answer (score 3):

`vlink` is null. This is probably because it's not in whichever layout you're loading that causes the crash.

Comment: But there are no errors on the screen, how should I know what to fix? :s

Comment: Because it's in your stack trace. Look in your layouts. Whichever one you're opening up to cause this crash I am fairly certain does not have a button with the id `videolink`.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to be a typo. The layout was all correct. The button id missed a letter!